# How do I load values into a wxPython app when it opens?

Tags: wxpython

I have a wxPython app that will have text boxes for things like UserID, Password, and Tunnel ID (for an IPv6 Updater). The values are saved in a txt file, so that the user won't have to keep entering them when they start the app. I've got a method called "ReadInformation()" set up to handle this, but I need to know where to call it in my app.

Essentially, what I want is for the window to open, and the values to be pre-filled into the text boxes from the file. I've tried calling ReadInformation() from various places, but nothing seems to work.  So, do I need to create an "OnLoad" type of event for the frame, or should I put the call somewhere else?

Here's a link to my current code http://bpaste.net/show/WjMo9nfHZJQH77Gza4w5/

Thanks, and have a great weekend.:)
Patrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call your method after creating the controls and before the frame is shown:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self._init_ctrls(parent)
    self.readInformation()
```

When the frame is created, `__init__()` is executed which creates the controls and populates the information (before it is made visible):

```
frame = Frame1(None).Show()
```

Alternatively you can call `readInformation()` after you create the frame:

```
frame = Frame1(None)
frame.readInformation()
frame.Show()
```

Also you may want to move `wx.Frame.__init__(...)` into the frame's `__init__` since it's the base class and not a control.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up putting it in the main App file, after everything was called and the frame was shown. I'll try your spots as well, just to find out the difference, and whether one is more efficient than the other.  Also, I'll look at the wx.Frame.__init__ method as well. BoaConstructor puts it where it's at now.